# Reading and multiplying sorted matrix

Tags: algorithm, sorting, matrix

I've got a problem concerning a few operations on two sorted matrices of size NxN. 
Namely, the matrices are sorted in a way that every single row and every single column is sorted in an ascending order. My task is first to read two matrices and then to multiply them which should produce another sorted square matrix. In this result matrix I've got to make a search for an element, but the problem is with time complexity limitation which is `O(n^2(lgn))`, whereas typical multiplying algorithm is around `O(n^3)`.

How can I look for elements simultaneously counting dynamically proper values? Could anyone help me to sort out this problem?  I've been struggling with it for a week or so and I still don't see a good solution for it.

I'll really appreciate any help from You!

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching an element in a sorted matrix can be done in `O(N)` time.

```
1. Start from lower left corner of the matrix A[N-1][0] (i = N-1, j = 0).  
2. If element is > A[i][j], go right (increment j).  
3. If element is < A[i][j], go above (decrement i).  
4. If element is == A[i][j], Stop with success.  
5. If i < 0 or j == N, Stop with failure.
```

Now you want to search for an element in a matrix that is a product of two sorted matrices.

IMO It can be done in `O(N^2)` time overall!

Simply apply the above searching algorithm and calculate the matrix elements on the fly. Calculating each element takes `O(N)` time because you multiply a row with a column. Hence overall complexity of the algorithm shall be `O(N^2)`.

Comment: Thank U for a great response! However I'm afraid if some values occur multiple times something might be overlooked. But I'll try to implement it. :) Thank U!

Comment: @vladimir1923 Can you give an example where the algorithm does not work?